# How to turn off "<em class="placeholder"> </em>" surrounding vars in the output of t()?

Tags: 7, routes

In my module I display a menu inside a block using `drupal_render(menu_tree('my-menu'))`.

In the output the variables printed with `t()` are surrounded by `<em class="placeholder"> </em>`.

```
Drafts <em class="placeholder">(4)</em>
Inbox <em class="placeholder">(2)</em>
```

How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is actually an [excellent comment in the documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7#comment-25348) for this. Pasting here for completeness

---

There are three styles of placeholders:

`!variable`, which indicates that the text should be inserted as-is. This is useful for inserting variables into things like e-mail.

```
$message = t("If you don't want to receive such e-mails, you can change your settings at !url.", array('!url' => l(t('My account'), "user/$account->uid")));
```

`@variable`, which indicates that the text should be run through check_plain, to escape HTML characters. Use this for any output that's displayed within a Drupal page.

```
$title = t("@name's blog", array('@name' => $account->name));
```

`%variable`, which indicates that the string should be HTML escaped and highlighted with theme_placeholder() which shows up by default as emphasized.

```
$message = t('%name-from sent %name-to an e-mail.', array('%name-from' => $user->name, '%name-to' => $account->name));
```

Comment: Sorry I should have checked that doc:$ I search for the HTML not for the function:$. THX